# Real-valued characteristic function of $X \sim U[-1, 1]$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

The characteristic function of the uniform distribution for $t\neq 0$ is:

$$\Large\varphi(t)=\frac{e^{itu}-e^{itl}}{(u-l)it}$$

with $u$ and $l$ corresponding to the upper and lower limits of the pdf:

$$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{u-l}$$

In [the Wikipedia entry for characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)) there is this plot:

[image]

with the caption:

> The characteristic function of a uniform U(–1,1) random variable. This
>   function is real-valued because it corresponds to a random variable
>   that is symmetric around the origin; however characteristic functions
>   may generally be complex-valued.

However, I'm stuck with a probably silly step:

$$\varphi(t)=\frac{e^{1it}-e^{-1it}}{(1-(-1))it}=\frac{e^{0}}{2it}= \frac{1}{2it}$$

How do you get rid of the imaginary part in the denominator?

---

CONCLUSION:

$$\varphi(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{(1-(-1))it}=\frac{2i\sin(t)}{2it}=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$

This is the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you believe that $$e^{it} - e^{-it} = e^0$$ but this is **wrong**. Instead you have to use the identity $$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$

Comment: Of course... So not used to work with complex numbers. Thank you. I'll addend the OP.